# sort according to distance in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, aggregation-framework, distance, geo

I have data in the following format in mongodb

```
[
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "location": [
            {
                "district": "district4",
                "cords": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "location": [
                        98,
                        27
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "district": "district6",
                "cords": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "location": [
                        98,
                        27
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }


]
```

I want to query for given lat-long and get data in the following format

```
[
    {
        "distance": 500,
        "district": "district2",
        "cords": {
            "type": "Point",
            "location": [
                98,
                27
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "distance": 500,
        "district": "district1",
        "cords": {
            "type": "Point",
            "location": [
                98,
                27
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

is it possible? I have gone through the documentation of MongoDB but cannot find any example similar to this problem

Comment: Not clear what you like to get. The sample input does not match the sample output and providing two equal coordinates does not make much sense in order to describe your problem. Is your input one document with two coordinates (if yes, then which coordinate you like to query?) or should these be two documents?

Comment: Have a look at [$geoNear](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/).

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit this is just dummy data to show the structure of my DB in practical that actual coordinates and not the same and I am not able to do it with $geoNear can you share your query on the same.

Comment: Yes, if you provide some realistic data and answered my question.

Comment: As you have an array of coordinates in your one document, If we use `$geoNear` it will only be able to insert a single distance field. If you are flexible to change the data structure then we can use `$geoNear` and then create a `view` which can display the data in your current format